# Drupal 7: Site-wide Taxonomy restrictions--Enforcing 1:1 term:node relationships for specific terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I'm developing an online magazine, and am using Views to generate blocks for the homepage.

I am using a slightly customized Article as the content type for most of my data, with Views providing blocks with the necessary fields from those Articles. For example: the `Latest Blogs` View shows the `Short Headline` and `Teaser` fields, but the `Top Headline` View provides a block with the `Image` and `Full Headline` fields.

Right now I'm using Views to filter Article by tag, so Articles need to be tagged to show up on the homepage. Most of my blocks are lists and don't need the tightest sorting flexibility. However, some blocks are not lists, or it's important for the end user to have control over the display order of Articles in certain blocks. Is there a way to enforce site-wide 1:1 tagging for term:article relationships. For example, I want to ensure that only one Article is tagged `top.news.1` (the first Top News slot), and likewise only one article is tagged `top.news.2`. When someone wants to add `top.news.2` to an Article, the one Article that already has that tag will lose it. Or something like that.

I have played around with Views enough to gather that it is really powerful, so this level of microcontrol might not be necessary with the right configuration, but I think restricting taxonomy versus configuring Views filtration would address the problem more directly.

I've looked around the web and haven't been able to find anything really relevant. Sorry if I missed something obvious.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it correct that you (or your site editor) want the ability to:

- spotlight a certain nodes
- arbitrarily change the order of the spotlighted nodes, or add/remove a node from the spotlight while keeping the position of the other nodes?

If so, your best bet is likely [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue), which does exactly that, and allows you to restrict the number of nodes spotlighted. It's very easy to use and our non-technical clients have no problems with it.

If your use case is different from that or requires more flexibility, Nodequeue may not be the right fit, but it works great for the specific example you're describing.

Comment: Hi g_thom, thanks so much for reading my question and for the great-seeming lead. I took a look at this module and yes, this does seem pretty much up my alley. Switching over to this approach will take some reconfiguring so I'll check it out on my development branch when I can. Thanks so much in the meantime.